# Deploy a Flask WSGI application to AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, aws-lambda

I want to deploy my Flask application to AWS Lambda. I tried deploying it using aws-cli, but it wasn't successful. How can I deploy Flask to Lambda?

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/status', methods = ['GET','POST'])
def service_run():
    return "service is running"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deploy a Flask WSGI application to AWS Lambda using [Zappa](https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa/). Install `zappa` and configure it:

```
pip install zappa
zappa init
```

Then deploy it with:

```
zappa deploy
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, it will generate only one url right ?

Comment: It's all about the route. Yes it will give you one url generally like domain name and then you can access the flask route `/whatever`. i.e) zappa give your url like this `https://something.aws.lambda.com/api` then you can access info using `https://something.aws.lambda.com/api/info`

Comment: hi @Raja, I tried zappa it was working fine for simple hello world program

Comment: but for my flask function im getting `An uncaught exception happened while servicing this request. You can investigate this with the `zappa tail` command` pls help

Comment: hi zappa tail is not working `(.env) C:\Users\ELCOT\.aws\flask-app>zappa tail
usage: zappa [-h] [-v] [--color {auto,never,always}]
             {certify,deploy,init,package,template,invoke,manage,rollback,schedule,status,tail,undeploy,unschedule,update,shell}
             ...
zappa: error: Please supply a stage to interact with.`

Comment: Oh no sorry I forget the actual error message. It's says Please supply a stage to interact with. When you deployed using zappa did you push to development or production ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169474/discussion-between-raja-simon-and-chandru).

Comment: Hi Raja, I am trying to replace this sqldb db with mongoeb, https://github.com/jonalxh/Flask-Admin-Dashboard , I tried many ways but nothing works, please send me any reference or help @raja simon

Comment: Please understand that `Flask-Admin-Dashboard` created using Flask-SQLAlchemy` which means it only supports SQL but in your case you're trying to deploy `MongoDB` which is No-SQL and you think this will work out of the box ?

Comment: what's wrong, I am trying to use the same Dashboard and changing only the database. why it will not work?, or pls give me a reference link to use flask admin crud operations from mongodb

Comment: If you choose MongoDB then you need to change all the codebase. Because flask-sqlalchemy is SQL database library.

Comment: yes, we cannot use sqlalchemy, I am going with pymongo. I can get all required data from mlab easily with pymongo but I dont know how to display and perform the crud operation, that's why asking you

Comment: I'm suggesting you to change or refactor all the crud operation in `Flask-Admin-Dashboard`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170958/discussion-between-raja-simon-and-chandru).

Answer (score 0):

You can host the flask app on AWS using Elastic Beanstalk service of AWS instead of trying to use AWS Lambda. By doing it this way, your app would get hosted on a public URL so that you can access it anytime. This is the quickest way to launch a flask app on AWS.

For more details on how to host a flask application on AWS, refer the below link:

[Hosting a flask app on AWS Elastic Beanstalk](https://github.com/kmrambo/Deploying-a-Flask-or-Dash-application-using-AWS-Elastic-Beanstalk)